# How to convert python hash of array of hash key to array?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, hash

I have an python dictionary like this

```
products = {'results': {'images': 'http://static13.jassets.com/p/Gini-26-Jony-Green-Casual-Shirt-9007-7386721-4-zoom.jpg', 'offers': {}, 'name': ['\n            Green Casual Shirt        '], 'features': {}, 'brand': ['\n            Gini & Jony        ']}}
```

How could i convert images  key to an array?

for now images is like

```
{'images': 'http://static13.jassets.com/p/Gini-26-Jony-Green-Casual-Shirt-9007-7386721-4-zoom.jpg'}
```

but i want images to be an array

```
{'images': ['http://static13.jassets.com/p/Gini-26-Jony-Green-Casual-Shirt-9007-7386721-4-zoom.jpg','','','','']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
products['results']['images'] = [products['results']['images']]
```

Example: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_Axyo9e7dCYT1Q7o.py

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
products['results']['images'] = [products['results'][v] for v in products['results'] if v == 'images']
```